# Would asking about a clarification regarding the definition of a measure in datawarehousing be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, asking-questions

While trying to make sense of datawarehousing, I came across the following definition in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(data_warehouse)):

> In a data warehouse, a measure is a property on which calculations
> (e.g., sum, count, average, minimum, maximum) can be made. A measure
> can either be categorical, algebraic or holistic.

However, for instance, the count calculation can be made on every property/column. Would it be on-topic to ask whether that means that all properties or columns in a datawarehouse database are measures?

Comment: I thought it was just a marketing term, like [data assets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnq9syXUuFE&t=2h25m09s) and data lakes. (Note that the audio is about 10 seconds of a sync with the video.)

Comment: I would ensure that you've done some research beyond Wikipedia for sure. You might also check the meta sites for other sites in the Stack Exchange network that seem on topic, like [dba.se].

Comment: Just found a related question in dba.stackexchange:  [What are Measures and Dimensions in Cubes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45655/what-are-measures-and-dimensions-in-cubes)